# Unable to change Table Header Border Codeigniter Bootsrap

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I have one site which is built with codeignitor and bootstrap. I have one page in which I have table with below class.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gran Id</th>

                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

I am trying to change color of table header with style adding in my html code like below

```
<style>
th {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
} 

</style>
```

But its not working. I have tried lot but not able to do it. Let me know if someone can help me for solve the issue. Thanks!

Edit: 
Solution of @failedCoder is changing color but its not useful for gradient background. Its looking like below image, Let me know if someone can improve it.
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution is to use inline styling

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    // style attribute added
                    <th style="background-color: blue;color: white;">#</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gran Id</th>

                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

You can also try to use !important to over-ride any other styling on the element

```
th {
    background-color: blue !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Edit:

You can try to apply your styling to entire first row, instead of just targeting th element

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr id="first-row"> // id added to first row
                    <th style="background-color: blue;color: white;">#</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gran Id</th>

                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

CSS:

```
  #first-row   {
      ... do your stuff here
  }
```

Comment: actually I want add gradient background for it and so adding color for separate th one by one will not help me for achieve my goal. Thanks!

Comment: Yes second one is the one which I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't know why but last solution not working. Thanks!